# Поиск минимального и максимального значения в массиве

Tags: c++

Есть массив

```
const int N = 5
A[N] = {10,5,7,8,11}
```

осуществляю поиск минимума и максимума осуществляется как показано ниже:

```
int Max = A[0], Min = A[0]; 

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
if (Max < A[i])
Max = A[i];
if (Min > A[i])
Min = A[i];
}
```

Объясните на пальцах, почему именно так?
Ведь по сути получилось, что:

Максимумом и минимумом одновременно, назначен нулевой (первый) элемент массива. 
Дальше он по циклу сравнивает, нулевой элемент массива, с каждым следующим, и постепенно если нулевой больше или меньше следующего назначает минимумы и максимумы. Таким образом например массив A из [N] элементов, где N=5.И массив имеет следующие значения {10,5,7,8,11};

Я вижу что цикл по идее будет работать так:

```
шаг 1. 

If (10 < 5)
Max = A[0]
if (10 > 5)
Min = A[1]

шаг 2. 
if (10 < 7)
Max = A[0]
if (10 > 7) 
Min = A[2] - уже ошибка т.к. 5 < 7

шаг 3. 
if (10 < 8)
Max = A[0]
if (10 > 8)
Min = A[3]

шаг 4. 
if (10 < 11)
Max = A[4]
if (10 > 11)
Min = A[3]
```

Или программа работает не так? точнее она и работает не так, не понимаю логику, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: `он по циклу сравнивает, нулевой элемент массива, с каждым следующим,` - Разве в коде сказано `if (A[0] < A[i])`? Нет. Не нулевой, а текущие минимум и максимум, которые изменяются в ходе работы цикла.

Comment: спасибо огромное. Не знаю как Вас отблагодарить и поставить плюсик. Закройте тему. Теперь понял.

Comment: Ну, там уже два ответа написали, выберите, какой вам кажется наиболее подходящим, и поставьте галочку. :) Или напишите еще один ответ сами, это тоже будет полезно. :)

Comment: Так самое понятное объяснение у Вас: что указаны текущие минимумы и максимумы в теле If-а, которые назначаются в ходе работы цикла. А те два ответа, они такие же замудренные как объяснения моего преподавателя.

Comment: Ну, мне, честно говоря, лень переделывать комментарий в полноценный ответ. :) Напишите ответ сами, так чтобы было понятно и Вам, и тем, кто потом столкнется с такой же проблемой. :)

Answer (score 1):

Если пройтись по приведенным в вопросе итерациям:

```
// итерация 0
if (10 < 5)
    Max = A[0]
if (10 > 5)
    Min = A[1]

// итерация 1
if (10 < 7)
    Max = A[0]
if (10 > 7)  // здесь ошибка в условии
    Min = A[1]
```

Там, где ошибка, будет не 10, а уже 5, т.к. значение `Min` изменилось на предыдущей итерации (`Min = a[1]`).

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте я побуду отладчиком

```
шаг 1. 

If (10 < 5)
Max = 5 //не выполнится
if (10 > 5)
Min = 5 //выполнится

шаг 2. 
if (10 < 7)
Max = 7 //не выполнится
if (5 > 7) 
Min = A[2] - уже ошибка т.к. 5 < 7 //неправда, вы ошиблись
Min = 7 //не выполнится

шаг 3. 
if (10 < 8)
Max = 8 // не выполнится
if (5 > 8) 
Min = 8 // не выполнится

шаг 4. 
if (10 < 11)
Max = 11 //выполнится
if (5 > 11)
Min = 11 //не выполнится

Max - 11, Min - 5
```

Answer (score 1):

### Код, который вы представили на самом деле пример использования динамического программирования.

Пусть вас не пугает слово "динамическое программирование", в данном случае алгоритм очень прост и мы рассмотрим его подробно применительно к нашей задаче. Сформулируем алгоритм. Для простоты я буду его описывать для случая поиска максимума, для минимума всё аналогично.

Итак, у нас есть массив `A`, с индексами от `0` до `N - 1`, заведём переменную `M`. Теперь будем обновлять переменную `M` так, чтобы после 0-й итерации цикла в `M` лежал бы максимум массива `A[0]`, после 1-й лежал бы максимум массива `A[0], A[1]`, после 2-й максимум в `A[0], A[1], A[2]` и так далее, после k-й итерации в `M` будет лежать максимум первых `k + 1` элементов массива, то есть максимум его начала `A[0], A[1], ... , A[k]`.

Легко видеть, что если мы организуем такую процедуру, то после `N - 1` итераций цикла мы в переменной `M` получим максимум в `A[0], A[1], ... , A[N - 1]` , то есть в точности максимум во всём массиве.

Осталось только разобраться, как организовать такой цикл. Вначале надо взять `M = A[0]`, при первом шаге максимум массива из одного элемента это он сам и есть.

Как теперь сделать шаг? Если у нас есть максимум среди `A[0], A[1], ... , A[k]`, и он равен `M`, то максимум среди `A[0], A[1], ... , A[k], A[k + 1]` это либо `M`, либо вновь добавленный элемент `A[k + 1]`, в зависимости от того, превысил ли добавленный элемент уже имеющийся максимум.

Отсюда становится ясно, что новый максимум равен наибольшему из ранее найденного (то есть `M`) и вновь добавленного элемента (то есть `A[k + 1]`), это значит, что максимум `M` следует обновить таким образом: `M := max(M, A[k + 1])`. Ровно это и происходит внутри цикла при обновлении переменной `Max`:

```
if (Max < A[i])
    Max = A[i];
```

Вот и всё.

Алгоритмы, когда мы последовательно увеличиваем область охвата данных, обновляя на каждом шагу некую характеристику, используя её значение, подсчитанное на предыдущем шаге, известны под общим названием [Динамическое программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В данном случае это один из простейших алгоритмов этого типа.

Answer (score 0):

В коде НЕ сказано, что if (A[0] < A[i]). Нет! А указаны ТЕКУЩИЕ минимум и максимум, которые изменяются в ходе работы цикла.

Всем спасибо закройте.

Comment: Вы сами можете закрыть вопрос, выбрав из данных ответов какой-либо, который вам кажется наиболее полно отвечающим на ваш вопрос. Для этого слева от ответа нажмите на галочку, это отметит ответ как правильный.